# What's the advantage of Atlantean workers over other civilizations' counterparts?

Tags: age-of-mythology

Personally I am a builder than aggressor. Before Titans came out I was quite happy with Norse. The only reason I play with Atlanteans is I don't have to worry about drop sites but I think their military is quite low powered compared to other civilizations.

Apart from drop site, are there any other advantages to Atlantean workers?

Comment: ooo Mark, how keen of you mate!

Answer (score 5):

Just from my experience with playing the Atlantean (from a few years ago!), the advantages its citizen (i.e. villager) has seems to be balanced out by its disadvantages, so overall its effectiveness is about the same compared to, let's say, Greek villagers, but it does have an uphand on certain map types.

**Advantages:**

1. No drop site required (which you already know)
2. Faster gathering rate (roughly 2.2 - 2.3x faster than a Greek villager)
3. Higher hitpoints (160 vs 65 Greek)
4. Higher LOS (16 vs 14 Greek)
5. Higher hunting range and attack (14 vs 12 Greek and 12 vs 6 Greek respectively)
6. Slightly higher hack armor (30% instead of 25%)
7. Faster contruction / repair speed (about 2 times faster than Greek, except town center which is about 1.2 times faster)

**Disadvantages:**

1. Cost (3x more than Greek)
2. Pop (3 pop instead of 1 pop)
3. Training limit (allowed 25 instead of 80 like Greek)
4. Slightly slower movement speed (3.25 vs 3.8 Greek) This is really rendered moot by the fact that it doesn't need to move much in the first place.
5. Takes longer to train.

Stats aside, Atlantean workers have certain **strategic advantages** over other races as well:

1. Decentralized economy - this means raiders would have to go find each individual citizen in order to kill them as they could be spread anywhere around the map.
2. More hitpoints mean they have more time to get back to safety when being attacked
3. They have a slight advantage over others on maps with sparse resources as they don't need any drop site. On maps with more concentrated resource patches, however, this advantage is vastly diminished.
4. Unique to the Atlantean civ, any non-myth unit can be converted into
   a hero unit. This includes citizens. This makes them a lot more
   valuable and versatile than their counterparts and a viable option
   to counter myth units.

Comment: Thats quite a list there. I see each advantage getting cancelled by the disadvantage. For every 3 normal villagers in other civs, Atlantis has 1 villager. So gathering rate, hitpoints, training time, training cost, faster construction, gather rate, get cancelled off. Decentralized economy: Means if raiders find a group of 3 'A' civilians, they get to kill equivalent of 10 normal villagers. Heroes: Upgraded heroes actually have very less hit points. Not as useful as normal heroes when you are fighting a titan. So overall, the creators tried to balance it out with villagers but not with military

Comment: I agree that when a raider kills 1 Atl villager, it's roughly equivalent to killing 3 Greek ones. So it comes down to how strategic you are in spreading them out on the map. Putting all of them together in one spot = economy suicide and is a sure sign that you shouldn't be playing this civ in the first place...

Comment: On other note, do you think there is any particularly powerful civ in AOM for defender/aggressor?